# why when declare a dynamic variable, reserves more than specified

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have the following code

```
char *str = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char)*5);
printf("Enter a string: ");
scanf("%s", str);
printf("%s\n", str);
```

This code supposed will reserve 5 places in memory `ex: 5 * 8 bit`, this mean that will stores five characters.
Now, when enter any number of characters (not up to five only), does not occur any error whether in compile time or in run time.
**is this normal? or there is an error I did not understand in my code ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've allocated 5 bytes, but `scanf` will happily continue writing into *un*allocated memory. This is a buffer overflow, and the C runtime assumes you know what you are doing; no bounds checking is performed.

Don't use `scanf`. Use `fgets` to read a line of at most 5 bytes:

```
char *str = malloc(5);
fgets(str, 5, stdin);
```

If you type a line with more than 4 characters, `fgets` simply discards the extra characters.

Comment: In same subject, `char *str = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char)*10); printf("%d\n", sizeof(str));` gave me the size is 4, how 4 and I have assigned `sizeof(char)*10` ?

Comment: `sizeof` doesn't give you the length of a string; it's give you the size of a `char *`, which is typically 4 bytes. Use `strlen` to tell you the length of the string.

Comment: I mean if char is `8 bit` and I wrote `10` chars `sizeof(char)*10` 8*10 equal 80 bit, that mean 10 byte.

Comment: Yes, but `sizeof(str)` simply tells you the size of the pointer, not the size of the block of allocated memory that it points to. As far as I know, you cannot determine the size of an allocated block of memory from the pointer alone.

Comment: is there is any way to know the memory block size when declared, to use with `fgets(str, size, stdin);`. or must write it as const like `10`

Comment: You may have to read your input in several fixed-sized chunks, the concatenate them together, if you don't know ahead of time the maximum-size string you may need to read.

Comment: You can avoid overflow in scanf by using a field width specifier, like `scanf("%5s",a)` or with a variable width `scanf("%*s",size,a)` (which is slightly different from printf, where it sets the minimum width, and the precision formatter is used to fix the maximum width `printf("%.5s",a)`).

Answer (score 1):

C will not prevent you from shooting yourself in the foot. `scanf` will happily overwrite the buffer given to it, invoking undefined behavior. This error is not reliably detectable at runtime and will silently corrupt memory and break the runtime of your application in unpredictable ways.

It is your responsibility as the programmer to prevent this from happening - in this case, for example, by replacing `scanf` with much safer `fgets`.

Comment: if `scanf` not safe, also when using c++ `cin`, `cout` The same thing, can store more than what I specified.

Comment: @LionKing C++'s `cin` can be made safe by passing it an `std::string`. There is no way to make `scanf` safe, however.

Answer (score 0):

When you allocate memory dynamically, more space will be allocated than the specified. Generally `malloc` implementations round the size requested to the multiple of 8 or 16 or some other 2^n. That's may be the one of the reason that you are not getting any error.

Comment: But this is more than the normal, I can enter `ex:good morning Mr Animal, thank you for your visiting`, all that can store after using this code line `char *str = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char)*5);`

Comment: `malloc` never allocates more memory than specified. `scanf` simply doesn't care if memory it writes to is allocated or not.

Comment: @chepner; Yes it does.

Comment: Regardless of what rounding an implementation of `malloc` may do, it doesn't protect you from `scanf` attempting to write to an unlimited amount of memory.

Comment: is c++ `cin`, `cout` The same thing like `scanf` ?

Comment: @chepner; I never said that `scanf` will protect to go beyond the limit.

Answer (score 0):

You have indeed allocated space only for 5 bytes (i.e., strings up to 4 characters + the terminating NUL), but your `scanf` does not know that. It will blissfully overflow the allocated buffer. You are responsible for ensuring that this does not happen; you need to change your code accordingly. Overflowing the buffer is undefined behaviour so in theory “anything” may happen or not happen as a consequence, but in practice it tends to overwrite other things in adjacent memory, corrupting the contents of other variables and possibly even program code (leading to an exploit where a malicious user can craft the input string so as to execute arbitrary code).

(As an additional note, `sizeof char` is always 1 by definition, you do not need to multiply with it.)

Answer (score 0):

You asked for 5 chars, you get memory that can contain *at least* 5 chars; the allocator is free to give you more memory for its internal reasons, but there's no standard way to know how much more it gave to you.

Besides, normally there's no immediate error even if you actually overflow a buffer like you did - the standard does not mandate bounds checking, it just says that this is "undefined behavior", i.e. anything can happen, from "your program seems to work" to "universe death" passing through nasal demons.

What *actually* happens in most implementation is that you will happily write over whatever happens to be after your buffer - typically other local variables or the return address for stack variables, other memory blocks and allocator's data structures for heap allocations. The effect usually is "impossible" bugs due to changing unrelated variables, heap corruption (typically discovered when you call `free`), segmentation faults and the like.

You must be very careful with this kind of errors, since buffer overflows not only undermine the stability of your application, but can also be exploited for security breaches. Thus, never carelessly write in a buffer - always use functions that allow you to specify the total size of the buffer and that stop at its boundaries.